# How to write a function to do cross product of two vectors in C

Tags: c, matrix, vector, cross-product

I'm writing a function in C that takes two vectors, v1 and v3, and performs a vector times vector multiplication to create a matrix.
v1 is a 1xL1 vector and v3 is a 1xL2 vector. The method takes the transpose of v3 times v1 and prints the matrix. This is what I have so far:

```
 void crossProduct(float *v1, float *v3, int L1, int L2){
      int i, j;
      float sum;
      float c[L2][L1];
      for(i = 0; i < L2; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < L1; j++){
          sum = 0.0;
          sum += v3[i] * v1[j];
          c[i][j] = sum;
          printf("%d", c[i][j]);
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm not getting the expected outcome. I also want to matrix to print in matrix form but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Is the `sum = 0.0;` in the wrong place, or is it simply unnecessary as the next lines should be `c[i][j] = v3[i] * v1[j];` without the variable `sum` at all?

Comment: The compiler should already have told you about wrong format specifier in `printf`. Did you enable warnings? If not, here is the answer, why you should always do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `%f` format for floats, not `%d`.

To get a readable array, put a space after each value, and a newline after each row.

```
 void crossProduct(float *v1, float *v3, int L1, int L2){
      int i, j;
      float sum;
      float c[L2][L1];
      for(i = 0; i < L2; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < L1; j++){
          sum = 0.0;
          sum += v3[i] * v1[j];
          c[i][j] = sum;
          printf("%f ", c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
      }
    }
```